# Xamarin.ios designer System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to open my Main.Storyboard in visual studio for mac, and i am getting 'System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred'. Note that i happened after upgrading Visual Studio to 7.3, the latest up to now and X Code to 9.2, also the latest available to now.
I am getting the following error screen

[image]

Comment: Try to restart vs or your mac.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work! :-(

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Tried restarting, reinstalling Visual Studio, makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, I have been having exactly the same problem for a week or two.

Originally, Visual Studio was installed under a non-admin user account (using an administrator password where prompted).

I eventually did a complete uninstall using the script mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall), and then reinstalled from scratch using an administrator account. This seems to have fixed the problem.

It seems that something failed silently during the earlier installation. I was a bit suspicious because the Visual Studio app didn't have its own icon - it was using the standard MacOSX document icon. Having reinstalled, it has the correct purple icon.